# How can I negate a lambda Predicate?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

Lets say I have a Stream of Strings.

```java
final Stream<String> stream = ...;
```

I want to filter out each empty string after trimmed.

```
stream
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty());
```

Is there any way to apply [Predicate#negate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--) for replacing `v -> !v.isEmpty()` part?

```java
.filter(((Predicate) String::isEmpty).negate()) // not compile
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You would have to do `.filter(((Predicate<String>) String::isEmpty).negate())`

If you want, you can define

```
static<T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> p) {
    return t -> !p.test(t);
}
```

and then

```
.filter(not(String::isEmpty))
```

but I would just stick with `v -> !v.isEmpty()`

Comment: You could also do `return p.negate();`

Answer (score 8):

It seems like you have to cast to `Predicate<String>` for this to work:

```
.filter(((Predicate<String>) (String::isEmpty)).negate())
```

Of course, it would be much shorter to use a lambda in this case:

```
.filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating classes by yourself use [durian](https://github.com/diffplug/durian) utility library. It has a lot of [methods](https://diffplug.github.io/durian/javadoc/3.4.0/com/diffplug/common/base/Predicates.html): `and`, `or` and `not` of course:

```
import static com.diffplug.common.base.Predicates.not;

stream
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.map(String::trim)
.filter(not(String::isEmpty));
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from java 11 you can use [Predicate#not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate))

```java
import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;

stream
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.map(String::trim)
.filter(not(String::isEmpty));
```